# Deffered deep link throught playstore

Tags: android, google-play, deep-linking, deeplink

I'm trying to configure my deffered deep link, but it only works when my app is already installed, I've been [DeeplinkMe tutorial](https://portal.deeplink.me/documentation), but I only achieve downloading my app from playstore, when I open, it goes to main activity, not the one defined on Manifest. Here goes my **Manifest file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.guisantogui.randomize">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".randomGeneration.RandomizeActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".randomHistory.RandomizeHistoryActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_randomize_history"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "http://www.example.com/gizmos” -->
                <data
                    android:scheme="randomizer.app" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Deeplinkme configuration:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I recently wrote an exhaustive list of deeplinking methods available on Android.
It contains advantages/drawbacks for each methods and code snippets to help implement them.

What might work for you is a mix of [Referrer Receiver](https://simonmarquis.github.io/Android-App-Linking/#referrer-receiver) and [Deferred Deeplink](https://simonmarquis.github.io/Android-App-Linking/#deferred-deeplink)

Source: https://simonmarquis.github.io/Android-App-Linking/